# Both Shift keys not working on old laptop Samsung RV411 under Ubuntu MATE 22.04

Tags: keyboard, mate

After searching and reading all of the related questions in here, after doing all the workarounds suggested in the answers (there's too many so I won't describe them), my shift keys, both left and right, are still not working. The rest of the keys on my keyboard are working OK, Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the hardware IS working? It's kinda old so any part can be defective including the keyboard. Does it work with an external keyboard?

Comment: no, it's not the hardware because before to as this question i asked for changing it for a brand new one and the keys work under windows os. and, yes it works with usb exterbal keyboard